# Share buttons to share chosen image

Tags: social-networking, share-button

I have several images on a single page. And I need to make a separate set of share button for each image respectively. But when I use any external service I get shared a random image on a page with selection. Is there a way to select some one image to be shared with shared buttons?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [learn about structured meta data](http://blog.muschamp.ca/2013/09/25/structured-meta-data-is-sexy/). If you're going to have many many images on the same page you're going to need to learn to mark that up using [schema](http://www.schema.org/).